# Accepting a limited set of subtypes in a method argument

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, subtype

This is with C# and .net 3.5

Let's say I have the following method:

```
myMethod(myBaseClass mbc)
```

In my project, all the following classes inherit from myBaseClass.

```
ot1:myBaseClass
ot2:myBaseClass
ot3:myBaseClass
ot4:myBaseClass
```

Are there any tricks that will let me use myMethod with ot1 and ot3 but NOT ot2 and ot4, or do I basically have to overload for each type I want to allow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An interface. Change your method signature to

```
myMethod(ICastableAsMyBaseClass mbc)
```

Then have ot1 and ot3 implement `ICastableAsMyBaseClass`.

Comment: That wouldn't prevent classes not deriving from MyBaseClass from implementing the interface though. 
He could make it generic like that: 

myMethod<T>(T mbc) where T: MyBaseClass, ICastableAsMyBaseClass

Answer (score 2):

You could check the class of mbc at runtime, but obviously that would not prevent you from calling the method with the wrong time at compile-time.

If you want compile-time typechecking you need to overload the method for each type you want to allow.

Comment: With this particular solution you can just delegate both constructors to a private constructor that takes the base type. Now you get compile time safety and don't have to duplicate the constructor.